# Does measuring voltage drops between the EBC terminals guarantee the functionality or non-functionality of a BJT?

Tags: transistors, counter, repair, vintage

Do voltage drops across the terminals of a bipolar transistor, which fall within the catalog data, guarantee that such a transistor is working properly?
I am in the process of repairing and restoring an old HP5245L frequency meter. The device runs self-tests without any issues but does not receive external signals. During the measurements, I found that the signal disappears between the differential pair (collector of Q5) and the emitter follower (base of Q6). Voltage measurements at the terminals of the transistors fall within the expected values, i.e., Vbe around 0.6 VDC. Despite this, I suspect damage to the transistor either in the differential pair or in the follower. Before I replace the 4 transistors (access is difficult), I would like to know if this is the only way to determine whether a transistor is damaged or not.

[image]

And the whole schematic
[image]

Comment: I respect what you are doing. But you wrote something that bothers me (because I'm sure I'm not understanding you.) You said *"I found that the signal disappears **between** the differential pair (collector of Q5) and the emitter follower (base of Q6)."* But this is just a wire. The collector and base are directly connected in the schematic. It's your use of *between* which makes me think of the wire itself. Did you mean something else? Maybe you meant the emitter of Q6 doesn't appear to follow the collector of Q5? (Just want to be sure.)

Comment: @periblepsis Yes it could be said: there is no signal at the Q5 collector

Comment: The signal at the collector of Q6 should be less than 1/10 of the signal amplitude at the base of collector Q5 (and base of Q6). In general I wouldn't expect the transistors to be the cause of any problem. It is more likely to be other causes.

Comment: When the signal on Q5 collector disappear does the driving signal on Q1 emitter disappear also?

Comment: @KevinWhite there is none. Just a DC component 13VDC.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Q1 forms an emitter follower and it passes a signal with no problems.

Comment: @periblepsis DC component is everywhere: 10.4VDC at the base Q5 (2.45Vpp), 8.4VDC at the base of Q4 (3.44Vpp)

Comment: Well a coupled inductors in diff. pair probably serves to obtain sharp edge for fast turning on/off off Q6. Since there is used flyback from coils (high voltage little damped with R18) it can be a big source of failure. What is E1?

Comment: @JerzyP And +1 for adding the diagram expansion.

Comment: @JerzyPrzezdziecki - 13V at the collector of Q6 is impossible. If the supply voltage is 20V that implies a current of 140mA. The 560 ohm emitter resistor doesn't allow that. Investigate why those DC voltages are not correct. Measure resistor values and supply voltages.